# remove first N character in vim from selected line

Tags: regex, vim

```
/**
 * Definition for an interval.
 * struct Interval {
 *     int start;
 *     int end;
 *     Interval() : start(0), end(0) {}
 *     Interval(int s, int e) : start(s), end(e) {}
 * };
 */
```

I have this format code and want to uncomment the struct in vim to something like this:

```
/**
 * Definition for an interval.
 */
struct Interval {
    int start;
    int end;
    Interval() : start(0), end(0) {}
    Interval(int s, int e) : start(s), end(e) {}
};
```

right now I just use this :%s/\s*\s//gc to remove ' * ', but it will also affect the line ' * Definition for an interval.', not sure if vim have the way to select which line I want to replace. Or if there is another better way to move the * for comment.

Answer (score 4):

There are *exactly* 47.337 ways to do what you want. Here is one…

Move — `:m` — the first line matching `*/` — `/\*\/` — above the first line matching `struct` — `?struct?` —:

```
:/\*\//m?struct?-
```

Result:

```
/**
 * Definition for an interval.
 */
 * struct Interval {
 *     int start;
 *     int end;
 *     Interval() : start(0), end(0) {}
 *     Interval(int s, int e) : start(s), end(e) {}
 * };
```

Cut the three first characters — `:normal 3x` — of each line between the line just below the current one — `+` — and the first line matching `};` — `/};/` —:

```
:+,/};/norm 3x
```

Result:

```
/**
 * Definition for an interval.
 */
struct Interval {
    int start;
    int end;
    Interval() : start(0), end(0) {}
    Interval(int s, int e) : start(s), end(e) {}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can mark the lines with visual line mode <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>, and then use something like one of these:

```
" Remove leading space, asterisk, space
:s/\s\*\s//

" Remove leading 3 characters on line, whatever they are
:s/^...//
```

Then move the comment close `*/` up, to where the comment should now end.

Answer (score 1):

Another of the 47.337 ways... use visual block mode.

First move cursor to line 3 (`3G`), then

```
<ctrl-v>6jlldO */<esc>
```

or a more portable way:

```
<ctrl-v>/*\/<cr>ldO */<esc>
```

Btw: You can easily find out how many lines you have to move down (the `6j`-part) if you enable relative line numbers with `:set relativenumber`